# Why is the proper distance written like this? - General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, distance

I came across the following equation for proper distance:

$$ds^{2} = -c^{2}dt^{2} + [dx - v(t)f(r(t))dt]^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}$$

where the function $v(t)$ tells you the velocity of the warp spaceship, $r$ is the radius function from the ship to the warp bubble shell, and $f$ is the shape of the warp bubble. Similar: [https://www.sfu.ca/~adebened/funstuff/warpdrive.html](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Eadebened/funstuff/warpdrive.html) (**please scroll down to the first equation since it is similar to the one above**).

I want to understand why the 2nd term is written in this form: $[dx - dt]^{2}$ mathematically speaking and how it relates to General Relativity.

Is it because there is a nonzero value in the metric that is not a part of the main diagonal or the trace of the metric? For example:

$$g_{00}, g_{11}, g_{22}, g_{33}, g_{31}$$

are nonzero while all other entries are zero.

If this is the case, can you please provide some examples of how to write the proper distance when there are nonzero values in the metric that are not in the trace?

Please excuse me if I am asking a basic/simple question, I am only a beginner at General Relativity.

Comment: You should at least provide a reference to where you have seen this so people can go and see the context.

Comment: @Charlie I would if my question would not be closed. The context is not mainstream physics and it's why I made no mention of it since my question would be closed. However, I purely want to understand the math of it and not the actual physics of the non-mainstream concept and know where else could the math be written in the way I said above in mainstream physics. I guess I could provide the context, but then everyone should be warned that I am NOT asking about theoretical physics and be tolerant to my question.

Comment: If your question is just about the mathematics and not the physics then it is off-topic here, if your question is about non-mainstream physics it is off-topic here. Withholding the source doesn't make it any less off-topic.

Comment: “I am excluding the metric here since it is irrelevant to my question” The metric is absolutely essential to a question about proper distances.

Comment: @Charlie Yes, I agree with you that pure mathematics is off-topic and non-mainstream physics off-topic here as well, but I do wish to understand it since it allows me to better understand General Relativity. How? Well, think of it this way: I get to know how to interpret the non-trace values of the metric written in the proper distance equation.

Comment: @Dale Yes, agreed, the metric is necessary. However, please do refer to my first and second comments in this comment section to understand. Also, I added part of the metric to make sure I am talking about spacetime as the answer below has pointed out by Andrew Steane.

Comment: I read those comments and they are incorrect. There is no excuse or justification that makes the metric irrelevant to a question on proper distance. I have voted to close as it is missing crucial details.

Comment: I guess you are all right, my question should be closed. I am afraid it is too theoretical. Does anyone know where I could ask this kind of question where I can put the full metric and it won't be closed?

Comment: The question is not too theoretical, it's too unspecific. There are clearly problematic aspects about this metric, e.g. there's a $c^2$d$t^2$ term at the same time as an d$x - $d$t$ term. As previously mentioned, when asking about something that is non-standard, it is crucial to provide a context and even better to supply a source.

Comment: @TBissinger Ok, I will edit my question to provide the full metric.

Comment: It is not too theoretical, it is missing crucial information. To calculate a proper distance requires two things: a metric and a spacelike curve. Without those you cannot calculate proper distance.

Comment: @Dale I added a source and the full metric.

Comment: That is much better. I have retracted my close vote. AndrewSteane has a good answer. Especially the last paragraph is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line element equation (the equation for $ds^2$ in terms of coordinate changes) and the metric are just two ways of talking about the same thing. For the line element is
$$
ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu
$$
so to write $ds^2$ in terms of $dx^a$ IS to write the metric; the coefficients are the elements of the metric. In the example you furnished (after two edits)
the metric under consideration is
$$
[g_{ab}] = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
v^2 f^2 - c^2 & -v f \;&  0\; & 0\\
-v f & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
$$
If this metric is connected with a discussion of warp drives etc. then there is a strong possibility that it cannot occur in nature, but I have not checked that.
You have to beware, in this area, that sometimes people announce results that are based on the assumption that something could have negative mass, or something like that. The assumption may be hidden however, and one way to hide it is to propose a metric. But a metric implies a configuration of matter, and if the configuration of matter has negative mass then basically you can forget it.
An assumption of negative mass is questionable even as a tentative hypothesis, since it leads to other considerations that the proposer might not have thought about, such as that spacetime then becomes unstable. Unless consideration is given to that, the discussion fails to have any useful contribution to make to understanding the actual universe---the one that science is concerned with.

You might want to note also that when the metric is not diagonal it requires careful interpretation. Often the coordinate labelled '$t$' does not represent time in any straightforward sense.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, but the equation I provided was not complete. I omitted the metric since the metric has to do with theoretical physics. Please read my comment under my question for more.

Comment: I edited my question to make sure I am talking about spacetime.

Comment: @TBissinger the question got edited after I posted my answer. I have now adjusted the answer to fit the edited question. But I suspect the real problem here is the questioner is trying out ideas with little or no training.

Comment: Indeed. I'll erase my comment.

Comment: I have added the full metric and a source.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I thought I could understand something with this idea, but you convinced me otherwise.